# Draining of nodes freezing

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am migrating work loads with the manual from https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool
But when running following command from step 4. the draining runs for while and then just freezes with the daemonset error message and stays there

`for node in $(kubectl get nodes -l cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool=default-pool -o=name); do
  kubectl drain --force --ignore-daemonsets --delete-local-data --grace-period=10 "$node";
done
node "gke-staging-default-pool-28djdc82q-1kbf" cordoned
node "gke-staging-default-pool-28djdc82q-7knh" cordoned
node "gke-staging-default-pool-28djdc82q-jrpp" cordoned
pod "pod1" evicted
pod "pod2" evicted
pod "kube-dns-2928dhhh3w7-7qljt" evicted
<nothing happens here>`

Does anybody know how to get around this?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/53594

Comment: It is possible that a pod(s) is not exist anymore and it stucks in 'terminating' stat . You can find that pod using command **kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces | grep <node_name>**. If so [delete](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#delete) that pod.